# Switching voice or accent during Speak Screen when reading same language

Tags: iphone, accessibility, language, voice, speech

I hope to switch the voice on different languages via Speak Screen. It switches voice and accent on different sentences or paragraphs even when all the text is in the same language, in my case English.

- Nothing to do with any translation being needed.
- This happens on web pages and pdfs and not just on word processor
  documents where there might be a language field embedded.
- I've got an English UK voice installed and reading an English document it keeps switching to a Spanish sounding voice speaking in English that is
  very difficult to understand and yet there is no Spanish sounding
  voice installed on the phone.

Using iOS 14.4 so everything is up to date. Please help with my project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Voice in iOS switches language during text-to-speech](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346014/voice-in-ios-switches-language-during-text-to-speech)

Comment: Saying “I’ve searched“ is a guaranteed way to get down votes. See [help] and the [tour] on how to document specific searches that explain how your research isn’t helping to avoid close votes.

Comment: All I can say is my search identified the "Voice in iOS switches ..." article identified above.  However, that article refers to the voice changing when it encounters text in different languages.  In my case, the voice switches to another language on alternate paragraphs, even when the text is in the same language, so the article doesn't really apply.  Notwithstanding this, I tried the solution provided in that post and it didn't solve my problem.  However, thank you for pointing this out.  I did genuinely try to search for all possible answers before posting a new question.

Comment: I think maybe the text of my post may have been edited or moderated so that it doesn't quite explain my problem.  I am not trying to make the accent change when it encounters a new language.  The accent is automatically changing even when the language stays the same, and I am trying to find a way to prevent this.